# Win 7 and Ubuntu Dual Boot: Use of Mono

Tags: windows-7, monodevelop, ubuntu-12.04

What should be the best Ubuntu version to actually use **MonoDevelop** to code .NET apps?
Also, I want to keep Win 7 and Ubuntu in dual boot.

Experts can you please reply to this query, as to what can be pros and cons, and what version of Ubuntu to use.

I currently have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my laptop.

Regards

Anurag

Comment: I read on MonoDevelop site that they don't have stuff for 12.04...So I will have to get rid of it..hence posted a question as to what should be the correct combo...

Comment: It says 'Packages for MonoDevelop 4.0.12 not yet available. The latest available version is MonoDevelop 2.6.0.1'

Comment: Also, Packages Ubuntu 10.4 Packages at badgereports.org